# automate assembling multiple tiles back into the original big picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, tiles

I have multiple, 1024 jpeg tile images that are effectively tiles of a one big image which was split into a matrix of 32×32 smaller ones (each 256×256px).

I wonder how could I efficiently put them back together as a single (psd?) file, ideally avoiding recompressing/reformatting (preserving originals as layers or even better, storing only links to the original tiles?)

Would that be possible?

The tiles are named using a convention:

```
img_01_01.jpg img_02_01.jpg … img_32_01.jpg
img_02_01.jpg img_02_02.jpg … img_32_02.jpg
      ⋮             ⋮               ⋮  
img_01_32.jpg img_02_32.jpg … img_32_32.jpg
```

I'm able to create an html that shows all the tiles together but now I would like to be to have all the PS flexibility to work on with the stitched image.

Comment: Look into using imagemagick

Comment: I think that would modify (recompress) original files…

Comment: no, why would it.

Comment: It's *manually* possible to place each tile as a smart object (linked) in a single PSD then arrange them properly.